# Line breaks in a YAML file

Tags: javascript, yaml

I'm using javascript to write a YAML file, but it's invalid.

I'm writing it with one string using \n line breaks:

```
'dir: ./_data/'+language+'\npath: '+options.path+'\nname: work'
```

My question is, is this the correct way to break between the vars in a YAML file? It does not seem to validate.

Comment: Looks valid to me. What validator do you use?

Comment: http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: yamllint.com is adhering to YAML 1.1, that version was superseded by YAML 1.2 back in 2009. I wouldn't recommend it for validation unless you explicitly write YAML 1.1 (starting with a directive indicating you do so).

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to say without knowing what the language and options.path variables are.

This:

```
dir: ./_data/some_language
path: some_options.path
name: work
```

is valid YAML, even if you don't have a newline at the end of the file (I recommend to put a `\n` at the end of your string).

However if the variable `options.path` starts with a `*` you'll get an error about an undefined alias. If that value has `:` (colon + space) in it you'll get an error as well (mapping values not allowed).

You will also get an error if there are spaces before the first key (`dir`).

So it **could** generate correct YAML, but it **might** generate invalid YAML, depending on the values of the variables. The line breaks however, are at the right place.